# Replace 2 \n in text to <br \> in php?

Tags: php

i know the `nl2br` function in php to replace '\n' to `<br \>`,

but how to replace \n\n to `<br \>`.

for example:

```
string=

'paragraph
1

paragraph2'
```

it is expected to show

```
paragraph1

paragraph2
```

p.s. i have a form to input the text.
Any help is most appreciated :)

Comment: `str_replace("", "<br/>", $string);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace it easily with some simple regex:

```
preg_replace('/\n+/', '<br/>', $string);
```

Comment: Except this doesn't replace a single `\n` with the empty string, as per the example.

Comment: failed, just appear the same to the nl2br

Comment: Just had to do some research. :)
I just tried with an input and it works flawlessly. Could you show the forms code?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$string=

'paragraph
1

paragraph2';


$arr_temp = explode("\n", $string);
$prev_blank = false;
foreach($arr_temp as $str)
{
    if(trim($str)=="")
    {
        if(!$prev_blank)
        {
            echo "<br/>";
            $prev_blank = true;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo trim($str);
        $prev_blank = false;
    }

}
```

**output:**

```
paragraph1
paragraph2
```

Answer (score 0):

i've solved the problem.

just use

```
str_replace("\n\r\n", "<br />", $model->solutionText);
```